# How to set a timeout for multiple observables

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a scenario where I have two observables, each one returns an item from an API call.

What I want to do is:

- Execute both api calls concurrently.
- Set a timeout value (500 milliseconds) for both methods to finish.
- Receive the result from both after they finish, if both took less than the timeout value (500 milliseconds) I'll receive the results from both, if one only finishes then I want to receive its result and receive an error or a null value of the second.
- If both didn't finish within the timeout, I want to receive an error.

I Appreciate any hints on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both your api return an Observable which has emissions of type T, the first step is modify these observables so that they timeout. 
You can do that using the `amb` and `Timer` function.

```
Observable<T> apiCall1WithTimeout = Observable.amb(apiCall1(), 
                                                   Observable.Timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                             .flatmap(l -> Observable.error(new Exception("Api1 timed out")));
Observable<T> apiCall2WithTimeout = Observable.amb(apiCall2(), 
                                                   Observable.Timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                             .flatmap(l -> Observable.error(new Exception("Api2 timed out"))));
```

The second step is to further modify your observables so they do their work on different threads. This is done using the `subscribeOn` operator

```
Observable<T> apiCall1WithTimeoutNewThread = apiCall1WithTimeout.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
Observable<T> apiCall2WithTimeoutNewThread = apiCall2WithTimeout.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
```

The final step is to merge the emissions from your observables, but you want any timeout errors to be emitted last, luckily the `mergeDelayError`
operator does just that so

```
Observable<T> mergedCalls = Observable.mergeDelayError(apiCall1WithTimeoutNewThread, apiCall2WithTimeoutNewThread);
```